# EBO, multiple inheritance and MVSC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I have encountered a problem when running my code built on MVS2019. The problem is "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'function' was corrupted.". I searched the web for answers and found out that the reasons are some curiosities with EBO in multiple inheritance on MVS: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/344224/class-derive-from-lambda-corrupt-stack.html

Here is the code:

```
template <typename... Callables>
struct overload : public Callables...
{
    using Callables::operator()...;
};

template <typename... Callables>
overload(Callables...)->overload<Callables...>;

enum class Type
{
    Double,
    Int,
};

TEST(overload_test, test)
{
    int i = 0;

    const overload function
    {
        [](int) { return Type::Int; },
        [i](double) { auto a = i; return Type::Double; },
    };

    //const overload function // in this case I get the error
    //{
    //  [i](double) { auto a = i; return Type::Double; },
    //  [](int) { return Type::Int; },
    //};

    EXPECT_EQ(function(0.0), Type::Double);
    EXPECT_EQ(function(0), Type::Int);
}
```

I found out how to solve the problem - use macro like this:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#   define EMPTY_BASES __declspec(empty_bases)
#else
#   define EMPTY_BASES
#endif

template <typename... Callables>
struct EMPTY_BASES overload : public Callables...
...
```

And it worked for my concrette cases! But I continued testing it with different statefull and stateless lambdas and std::functions and realized that there are some cases where I still get the error not depending on using/not using the macro (see comment in code above.

And now I have sometimes "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'function' was corrupted." error when I use the macro and when I do not use it! And it depends on the order of functors and their statefullness. I wonder if it is possible to make this beautifull overload work on Visual Studio at all.

Comment: The "stack around the variable ... corrupted" error is most likely because you somehow write out of bounds of some other local variables.

Comment: Have you looked at the output with `/d1reportClassLayoutChanges`? (See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/optimizing-the-layout-of-empty-base-classes-in-vs2015-update-2-3/)

Comment: I don't understand how EBO can cause stack corruption. This seems more like something in your code is *assuming* some layout, but VS is giving you a different layout, so your code breaks somehow. We need to see the code that is actually producing the error.

Comment: I do not understand too. Here is what I found when searching web https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/344224/class-derive-from-lambda-corrupt-stack.html
And it worked before I started using std-function and statefull lambdas. But the order of such functions initializing overload object makes difference.

Comment: I have added the code that causes the error and that works without the error.